# Error when asking Running Object Table (ROT) out of main thread

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, qthread, ole

I have this method to test if I successfully get ROT:

```
void func()
{
    IRunningObjectTable *rot;
    qDebug() << GetRunningObjectTable(0, &rot);
}
```

Everything's fine from main thread but not in a separate one:

```
func(); // qDebug prints S_OK (0)
QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(func); // qDebug prints E_UNEXPECTED (0x8000FFFF)
```

Compiling with MinGW 5.3.0 32bits.

I don't get why would it be different from the main thread than an other.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your thread function didn't invoke [CoInitialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objbase/nf-objbase-coinitialize) or [CoInitializeEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-coinitializeex) before invoking GetRunningObjectTable.

This would likely work from a thread

```
void func_in_thread()
{
    CoInitializeEx(nullptr,COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

    IRunningObjectTable *rot = nullptr;
    qDebug() << GetRunningObjectTable(0, &rot);

    CoUninitialize();
}
```